# Issues with Promises and throw new Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, try-catch, throw

i'm doing a bot for Discord(for music using youtube api) and he works "well" in all the things that we implemented, the problem is only when i call a playlist function or play function and the music that we have to play or add in the queue are blocked. I worked so much on that and i've found ways to detected these errors, but, sometimes it works and sometimes don't. If i do it in a way, work for some musics like playlist of ac/dc and don't work for one music in the indie folk playlist, but if i change a little bit the way, works for indie folk playlist but don't for ac/dc playlist. i'm nervous!

Okay, this is the function of my code that is with problem:

OBS: The problem is only in the part that i verify regionRestriction and allowed arrays. The problem it's that i don't know how do things correctly with promises and the variable bool/bool2 don't get the correct value before enter in the function next() or next2(). And have another times that they enter in the function, but the "throw new error" stops the running of my program. i'm doing try and catch when i call the pesquisarTime function, and when i catch some err, i just throw again this err, doing "throw new Error(err)", because in the play function, i catch again this error and finally shows the error message in the discord chat. Please, help me to fix that!

```js
async function pesquisarTime(idp, titlep){
    let linkYoutube = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + idp + "&part=contentDetails&key=" + config.ytapi;
    let response = await fetch(linkYoutube);
    if(response == undefined || response == null){
        throw new Error("Vídeo \"" + titlep + "\" inválido!");
    }
    let info = await response.json();
    let regionRestriction = "";
    let allowed = "";
    let bool;
    let bool2;
    let x = 0;
    let x2 = 0;
    try{
        regionRestriction = info.items[0].contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked;
        //console.log("regionRestriction = " + regionRestriction);
    }catch(err){

    }
    try{
        allowed = info.items[0].contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed;
        //console.log("allowed = " + allowed);
    }catch(err){

    }
    if(regionRestriction != undefined && regionRestriction.length > 0){
        bool = new Promise(function(resolve){
            for(x = 0; x < regionRestriction.length; x++){
                if(regionRestriction[x] == "BR"){
                    x = regionRestriction.length;
                    console.log("resolve region = true");
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else{
                    if(x == regionRestriction.length - 1){
                        console.log("resolve region = false");
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then(next(bool));
    }
    if(allowed != undefined && allowed.length > 0){
        bool2 = new Promise(function(resolve){
            for(x2 = 0; x2 < allowed.length; x2++){
                if(allowed[x2] == "BR"){
                    x2 = allowed.length;
                    console.log("resolve allowed = false");
                    resolve(false);
                }
                else{
                    if(x2 == allowed.length - 1){
                        console.log("resolve allowed = true");
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then(next2(bool2));
    }
    function next(result){
        if(result){
            console.log("bool region = true fiii");
            Promise.resolve();
            throw new Error("Vídeo \"" + titlep + "\" bloqueado na sua região!");
        }
    }
    function next2(result){
        if(result){
            console.log("bool2 allowed = true fiiii");
            Promise.resolve();
            throw new Error("Vídeo \"" + titlep + "\" Bloqueado!");
        }
    }
    let durationp = info.items[0].contentDetails.duration.replace("PT", "");
    durationp = consertarTempo(durationp);
    durationp = calibrar(durationp);
    return durationp;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Use async await

Comment: @Helpinghand Please, explain me how.